# Loopback 4: Authorization decoration of CRUDRestController - is it in anyway possible?

Tags: authorization, loopbackjs, loopback4, typescript-decorator

Wondering if anybody in the community has any experience or guidance on how one could use
Authorization decorators (or any custom decoration?)(https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Decorators_authorize.html) on  CrudRestController endpoints? (https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Creating-crud-rest-apis.html).

Looked at the src for [crud-rest.controller.ts](https://github.com/loopbackio/loopback-next/blob/365ad9cd37a6219c6522e4590953d22f8c465821/packages/rest-crud/src/crud-rest.controller.ts) and it just seems like there is no way to really do it.

It seems like it's not easily possible to use any decoration of endpoints in a CrudRestController without taking a very hacky approach  and/or wholesale duplicating the code in [crud-rest.controller.ts](https://github.com/loopbackio/loopback-next/blob/365ad9cd37a6219c6522e4590953d22f8c465821/packages/rest-crud/src/crud-rest.controller.ts) and that we'll have to basically write every endpoint for every model by hand.

Maybe someone has come up with something or has some guidance on an approach? Is the only way to use auth with CrudRestController with the AuthorizationComponent as of now to use Authorizer functions (https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Authorization-component-authorizer.html)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like one part lies in this :

https://github.com/loopbackio/loopback4-example-shopping/blob/9188104c01516a5cbd4ce13f28abe18bafef821e/packages/shopping/src/services/basic.authorizor.ts

```
 /**
   * Allow access only to model owners, using route as source of truth
   *
   * eg. @post('/users/{userId}/orders', ...) returns `userId` as args[0]
   */
  if (currentUser[securityId] === authorizationCtx.invocationContext.args[0]) {
    return AuthorizationDecision.ALLOW;
  }
```

So I ended up doing :

```
async authorize(
      context: AuthorizationContext,
      metadata: AuthorizationMetadata,
    ) {
        const parent = context.invocationContext?.parent
        const request = parent?.getBinding("rest.http.request").getValue(parent)
        const givenUserId = request?.body?.userId

        // next line finds out the user id in the JWT payload
        const jwtUserId = context?.principals[0]?.payload?.sub
        if (!jwtUserId || (givenUserId && givenUserId != jwtUserId)) {
            return AuthorizationDecision.DENY;
        } else {
            return AuthorizationDecision.ALLOW;
        }
    }
```

as my userId is provided in the http parameters (post form or get parameters)

I also use a custom JTWService to read the payload and make it available in the UserProfile.

This may not be the best way to do it, but so far it works. I am still working on finding out how to deal with read requests and add a filter on all of them by userId too using decorators I will post my finding here, if nothing better show up first here.